# How can I add both text and image in a folium popup

Tags: python, image, text, folium

I'm using ftft folium in python.

I created my map, with few points and I managed to add an image for every point in the map.

Nevertheless, I'm not able to add both image and text. Is it possible? How?

Is it possible to add both image and a link?

Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Folium enables passing any HTML object as a popup, including `bokeh <https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/>`__ plots,
but there is a built-in support for `vincent` and `altair` visualizations to any marker type,
with the visualization as the popover. See example: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Markers

Here is a code that you may try:

```
# Demo code
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[46.3, -123.7], 
               width='60%', height='80%', zoom_start=7, tiles="Stamen Terrain")

htmlcode = """<div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="Flowers in Chania" width="230" height="172">
<br /><span>Flowers in Chania</span>
</div>"""
tooltip = "Click me!"

folium.Marker(
    [46.216, -124.1280], popup=htmlcode, tooltip=tooltip
).add_to(m)

m
```

The output:

[image: sample_output]